# How to make a php script overwrite a specific line of a txt file?

Tags: php

So I have a php script I am using to write a specific character to a txt file, outside of the php script an html button sets the character by setting the state using the button. I need to make more than one button now so that it can write to a different line in the txt file. So my question is, how would I make this script instead of overwriting the whole file instead overwrite say the second line of the file only?

```
<?php
$onoroff = $_GET["state"]; // Declares the request from index.html as a variable
$textfile = "LEDstate1.txt"; // Declares the name and location of the .txt file

$fileLocation = "$textfile";
$fh = fopen($fileLocation, 'w   ') or die("Something went wrong!"); // Opens up the .txt file for writing and replaces any previous content
$stringToWrite = "$onoroff"; // Write either 1 or 0 depending on request from index.html
fwrite($fh, $stringToWrite); // Writes it to the .txt file
fclose($fh); 

header("Location: index.html"); // Return to frontend (index.html)
?>
```

Any input would be great thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to read the whole file, edit and write it back

Comment: A nice function is: `file()`. <- Give it a look.